# Can I convert Selenium IDE testd to Selenium webdriver tests in Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, ghost-inspector

I am recording my test using Ghost inspector. It does allow me to export the tests in Selenium IDE format. Can I use the exported test to write Selenium web driver tests in the future (JAVA)

The exported tests look something like this:

1. Navigation
   waitForPageToLoad
   waitForElementPresent   css=.explore-nav-label
   click   css=.explore-nav-label
   waitForPageToLoad

Answer (score 2):

**Full disclosure: I work at Ghost Inspector.**

It looks like the Selenium IDE team has recently [added the ability to export tests](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/code-export) from the new Selenium IDE v3, which is great!

There will just be a couple steps involved:

### Export from Ghost Inspector

From the [Ghost Inspector dashboard](https://app.ghostinspector.com/), navigate to your test and select **More > Export this test** and then choose the **New Selenium IDE (.side)** format:

[image]

Click **Download** and save the file somewhere handy.

### Import (and export) using Selenium IDE

Importing into Selenium IDE is as simple as opening the `.side` file that you just downloaded from Ghost Inspector. Once you have the file open, you can right click on the test and choose **Export** in the left-hand pane. From there you will be given several formats to choose from, including Java JUnit:

[image: Export .side tests to JUnit]

### Some considerations

Keep in mind that the [Ghost Inspector step actions](https://ghostinspector.com/docs/test-editor/#actions) and the [Selenium IDE commands](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands) are not a perfect 1-to-1 match yet, so some of the actions from Ghost Inspector will show up as *JavaScript* actions in the Selenium format. You may need to make a few adjustments to your final test as desired.

Hope that helps!